# How to host a website in my network (localhost) using Java

Tags: java, localhost

So I am developing a program to host HTML files in the user's private network i.e. local host, but I have no idea how to implement this in Java. I have little knowledge about Java EE. If this is easier in another programming language (preferably C or Python) please emphasize upon it.

I tried looking at previous posts but they use Java Sockets, a handy tutorial is here :https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/sockets/

But I feel like this can be done easier with servers like Tomcat and Glassfish (please elaborate on this too).

Comment: Don't reinvent the wheel.  Look into SpringBoot and  use the embedded web server.  For a simply application, I'd go with Jetty,

Comment: maybe java is not needed at all, just to *host HTML files*. use existing web servers.

Comment: It all depends on the task you are doing. If you are building an application for distribution at scale you must use a framework like spring or jersey. If you are just making a simple serving application, you can even use the Simple HTTP Server in Java.

Comment: Do you mean host static files, or create dynamic content?

Comment: To host HTML files, you should use a web server like Apache, Nginx, or similar. I highly recommend not reinventing the wheel.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To host a website on your network, you have to use a socket. Like this:

1. Open a socket on port 8080 (default agreement for http when you aren't root)
2. Make a function that's can read html file and return what the file contains in a string (example index.html)
3. Make a function that's sent an HTTP request with html content do forget the content-length
4. In your main make a loop that iterates on new clients and send him the html

It's always the same method in Java or C, I invite you to look at this tutorial to do it in C:
https://www.binarytides.com/server-client-example-c-sockets-linux/

You can also read this:
https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E21764_01/core.1111/e10103/intro.htm#ASCON112

If you can do all the 4 steps, then your going to understand how works middleware then you can use TomCat, etc... Always start with the basics.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use Java to deliver static content, prewritten HTML files, any of the [web containers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_container) can be used. Apache Tomcat and Eclipse Jetty are two of the simplest.

If you want to use Java to create content dynamically, start by learning about [Jakarta Servlet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jakarta_Servlet) (formerly Java Servlet) technology.

Many web container products support Servlets. These include Tomcat, Jetty, Glassfish, Payara, WildFly, JBoss, OpenLiberty, and more.

From there, you may want to leverage additional libraries and frameworks. Two of the most popular collections of such libraries and frameworks is Jakarta EE and Spring.

You do not need to implement sockets. The web browser and web server handle all the networking automatically.

[WebSockets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebSocket) is something else. If really interested in that, see the [Atmosphere](https://github.com/Atmosphere/atmosphere) framework.

Comment: isn't there a room for netty?

Comment: @LeiYang [Netty](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Netty_(software)) is a framework that could be used to build a web server but is not itself a ready-to-deploy web server.